# Why Isn't My Ethernet Working?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, networking, led, ethernet-port

I just got Pi Model B. I downloaded Wheezy on SD card and plugged in all of my cords. Everything works fine except the Ethernet port.

The `LINK LED` flickers for a second while booting up, but then it doesn't do anything and they stay OFF. The browser shows NO CONNECTION.

I checked the cable, and when connected to laptop it shows connections, so the cable is still good.

I tried using `1A` and `700mA` power supplies as few people had suggested, but it didn't work.

I tried removing USB wireless keyboard / mouse, as it may drain power. Didn't work either. I tried removing HDMI too; it didn't work.

I had ordered 2 units from UK. 1 for me and 1 for my friend. The Unit I gave to my friend is working fine on ArchLinux and everything from SSH is working fine on that.

Can it be hardware problem? If yes can I use any WiFi adapters over USB?

I haven't tried the deep freeze method few suggested (keeping the Pi in fridge for couple of hours seem to make USB / Ethernet work for some folks) but I don't want to do it as it may damage the board.

Comment: Have you tried using Putty or another SSH client to login remotely to your Pi? or 'Pinging it'? You can use wifi adapters, check the list here : http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I though problem was that I was using a cheaper CAT5 cable, so I changed it with the one that came with my router.

**Solution :**

And gave a nudge to X1 crystal. And voila ! LINK LEDs lit up like Christmas tree :)

Now Ethernet works with both cables.

**Problem (I'm just guessing) :**

So I am assuming that there was loose soldering near X1 and it was not oscillating.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "giving a nudge to X1 crystal"? I have the same problem but do not understand what to do at all (electronics noob here ;))

Answer (score 6):

Please show the output of `ifconfig -a` and `dmesg|grep eth0`

By the way, it's easy to setup USB WiFi: plug in a compatible adapter, check if you see it as "wlan0" in `ifconfig -a` output (with HWaddr etc), modify 'wlan0' section in `/etc/network/interfaces` (assuming you're using WPA/WPA2 password-protected network with DHCP), then reboot:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "YOUR NETWORK NAME"
wpa-psk "YOUR PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Thanks @vk2 :) But finally I got ethernet to work

Comment: +1 for the easy wifi setup- i searched for this before and got really long tutorials installing helpers and junk. lol

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, Laptop worked ok when plugged into Ethernet - pi didn't (flashing lights only) using the same cables.

In the end, I opened the Ethernet port (RJ45 socket in the wall) and a couple of the cables were not punched down correctly - punched in, and it is all working.