# How do I configure a USB WiFi Dongle from the command line?

Tags: networking

I have a Pi, and with a fresh install, I can configure wifi connectivity using a helpful tool in X windows nicely.

However, what are the command line tools for configuring WiFi? What configuration files are updated?

This isn't critical, but I'd like to know.

Comment: [see here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/why-isnt-my-ethernet-working/4486#4486)

Comment: That looks like a good answer. Stick it here, and it'll be easier for people to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this, assuming the standard WPA2 necured network:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Enter this text, replacing the details with yours (`id_str` is just a comment, you can leave it as-is):

```
network={
    ssid="TheGarNetwork"
    psk="lollzthisisanexcellentpssword"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    id_str="Home_Wi-Fi"
}
```

CTRL-X, then press Y, then press Enter to save.

Next, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add this to it:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

iface default inet static
    address 192.168.1.128
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1(`allow-hotplug` is optional, if you're likely to be unplugging and replugging the adapter, and don't want to have to manually reconnect.)
Fill in the IPs with the appropriate details, or (if you don't want to deal with that,) just replace the word "static" with "dhcp" and delete everything after it.

When you've got that done, reboot and see what happens!

Comment: I recently switched to a wired connection, and in the process I trashed all my config files. This tutorial was created from memory, with a little help from Google, so please feel free to ask me for help if something doesn't work. (If you currently have a functioning Wi-Fi connection, and see an error in this post, please fix it for me or tell me about it. Thanks!)

Comment: ssid, key_mgmt and psk is often enough, the others are automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit /etc/network/interfaces and add these lines :

```
pre-up wpa_supplicant -B w -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

You can then "connect" to your network simply by typing

```
ifup wlan0
```

..And disconnect

```
ifdown wlan0
```

Saves the user from having to reboot the machine..

Here is where I took it from.. [Source](http://and-junk.com/?page_id=7)