# Mini usb power cable and ethernet connection

Tags: usb-power, ethernet

I bought a brand new Raspberry Pi. It came with a 5v ~ 1A power adaptor and a mini-usb cable.
I plugged it in and plugged in my cat 5 into the ethernet port. The raspberry powered up but the Ethernet LEDs were not lighting up. After trying a lot of different things I decided to replace the mini-USB cable with a phone-charger cable. And it worked!! The ethernet LEDs came on. Mind you, I was still using the power adaptor that came with the Rasp Pi, I just replaced the Mini-USB cable.
Can anyone tell me what was the issue here? Do mini-USB cables have varying power rating or grades? What did I miss here? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Isn't My Ethernet Working?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/why-isnt-my-ethernet-working)

Comment: Raspberry Pi has **micro** USB (type B) socket not mini USB for connecting a power cable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Host_and_device_interface_receptacles

Answer (score 1):

**Some possible issues:**

- You might be using a usb extension cable. USB looses power with range.
- The power adapter might say 1A, but can be lower then the label says.
- Try to disconnect so that both USB ports are available. If you have a usb-wifi dongle or something else that is consuming power, then you can have weird power issues.

**Additional info:**

- You can get Micro USB adapters in a range from 0,5 to 2,1A. ([Reference](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/159727-how-to-charge-your-smartphone-and-other-usb-devices-as-quickly-as-possible))
- Model A ratings: 300mA. Model B ratings: 700mA. ([Reference-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), [Reference-B](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/260))
- If you want a simple way of measuring how much power a USB device is using, you can buy [THIS](http://dx.com/p/usb-av-usb-power-current-voltage-tester-translucent-blue-silver-235090) device with free shipping. (5,99USD)

Answer (score 0):

basically cable should not matter, most probably it will work fine if you switch cables back.

if it does not -- you have another working cable, use it. could be a bad contact issue or higher resistance of the old cable -- there are just too many different factors to speculate about.